# What are __darwin_obsz() and __darwin_obsz0()?

Tags: c, macos, darwin

On MacOS, several functions including `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset`, and others are implemented as such, making use of a mysterious `__darwin_obsz0()` function:

```
#if __has_builtin(__builtin___memcpy_chk) || defined(__GNUC__)
#undef memcpy
#define memcpy(dest, src, len)                  \
  __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))
#endif

#if __has_builtin(__builtin___memmove_chk) || defined(__GNUC__)
#undef memmove
#define memmove(dest, src, len)                 \
  __builtin___memmove_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))
#endif

#if __has_builtin(__builtin___memset_chk) || defined(__GNUC__)
#undef memset
#define memset(dest, val, len)                  \
  __builtin___memset_chk (dest, val, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))
#endif
```

Similarly, `strcpy` makes use of a mysterious `__darwin_obsz` function:

```
#if __has_builtin(__builtin___strcpy_chk) || defined(__GNUC__)
#undef strcpy
#define strcpy(dest, src)                   \
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
#endif
```

What are these (macros?) functions and what do they do? I could not find any documentation about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like they are simple macros that expand to compiler built-ins to calculate the size of an object at compile time. This file [`include/secure/_common.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1244.50.9/include/secure/_common.h.auto.html) from Apple Open Source has their definition:

```c
#define __darwin_obsz0(object) __builtin_object_size (object, 0)
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 ? 1 : 0)
```

`__builtin_object_size` should be equivalent between Clang and GCC. The GCC documentation describes it [in this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html).

These sizes are passed as last argument to the `*_chk()` alternative of common memory copying functions such as `memcpy()` and `strcpy()`, supposedly in an effort to make the code more secure, trying to avoid memory corruption in case the wrong size is passed by the user, since the destination object size is checked by those functions.